# How to perform arithmetic operations of two different data types in thymeleaf?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-el

I have a piece of HTML where I need to multiply (or perform arithmetic operations) two values using thymeleaf.

Let's say my `price` is `double` and `quantity` is an `integer`.

Here's my sample code:

```
<fieldset class="form-inline" disabled >
    <label for= "prodAmount">AMOUNT:  </label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" th:text="${#aggregates.sum(product.![price * qty])}">
</fieldset>
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

`Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#aggregates.sum(product.![price * qty])"`

Also , I would also like to ask how to perform this when there's two or more values.

Here's my html form

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <form th:action="@{/product/product-list}" method="post" th:object="${productEntity}">
        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{pid}" th:value="${pid}" >
        <fieldset class="form-group">
          <label for="product_name">Product Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{pName}" th:value="${pName}">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="form-group">
          <label for="price">Price</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" th:field="*{price}" th:value="${price}" placeholder="0">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="form-group">
          <label for="pQty">Quantity</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" th:field="*{qty}" th:value="${qty}" placeholder = "0">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="form-group">
          <label for="status">Status</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="select_status" th:field="*{status}" th:value="${status}">
            <option value="0">AVAILABLE</option>
            <option value ="1">NOT AVAILABLE</option>
          </select>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="form-group">
          <label for="image">Image</label>
          <input id="input-b2" name="input-b2" type="file" class="file" 
                 data-show-preview="false" th:field="*{image}" th:value="${image}">
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <table class="table table-inverse table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Image</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr th:each="product : ${productTable} ">
          <td th:text="${product.pid}"></td>
          <td th:text="${product.pName}"></td>
          <td th:text="${product.price}"></td>
          <td th:text="${product.qty}"></td>
          <td th:text="${product.status == '0'} ? 'Available' : 'Not Available'"></td>
          <td th:text="${product.image}"></td>
          <td>
            <a th:href="@{/productlist/{id}(id = ${product.pid})}" class="btn btn-primary">Update</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row float-right">
    <div class="col-xd-12">
      <div>
        <fieldset class="form-inline" disabled >
          <label for= "prodAmount">AMOUNT:  </label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" th:text="${#aggregates.sum(product.{price * qty})}">
        </fieldset>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Checkout</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Product Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/product-list")
public ModelAndView shopView() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("productTable", pRepo.findAll());
    mav.addObject("productEntity",new ProductEntity());
    mav.setViewName("/productlist");
    return mav;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getProduct(@ModelAttribute ProductEntity productEntity, @PathVariable int id) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("productTable",pRepo.findAll());
    mav.addObject("productEntity", pRepo.findOne(id));
    mav.setViewName("/productlist");
    return mav;
}
```

Comment: `product` is a collection, right? and why do you have product `.![` exclamation  there? It  should be `${#aggregates.sum(collection.{price * qty}})` if you have single product, i think you should be able to use `${product.price * product.qty}`

Comment: i'm using a mysql as a datasource for product table in which the `qty` and `price` are in the same table.

Comment: @varren I tried your code and I encountered an error: `Expression [#aggregates.sum(product.{price * qty})] @23: EL1049E: Unexpected data after '.': 'lcurly({)'`

Comment: @user_boq: What is the exact type of your `product` variable? Can you confirm that it is a Collection of objects that have `getPrice` and `getQty` methods? Do you get a "caused by" exception with a more detailed error than just "exception evaluating"?

Comment: @PeterCooperJr. my `product` is from my ModelAndView object of product repository but my Product model only have a constructor.

Comment: @PeterCooperJr. I'm sorry I just found out my product model has getters and setters since I was using lombok

Comment: Now that you've posted your code (though a MCVE showing the issue you were having would be nicer), I have no idea what you're trying to do, which is why I think the SpEL interpreter doesn't know either. You're trying to use `product` outside of where it is defined, and I'm guessing it isn't a collection either. Maybe you want a projection on `productTable`? I'm not really sure what you're trying to do though, and I'm not convinced it's related to the multiplication itself.

Comment: @user_boq @Peter is correct that you are doing some strange processing here and we have no idea what is your goal. Also this has nothing to do with "2 different datatypes". But to help you a bit 1) you define `product` only in `<tr>` tag, so when you close this tag `</tr>` there is no more `product` variable in your scope. 2) if you want to sum all the products, use `${#aggregates.sum(productTable.{price * qty})}`

Comment: @varren so that's how it works. I thought defining the `product` variable would work like a global variable. I'm sorry for asking an unclear question and thank you for answering despite it.